# How can I remove the padding of the bootstrap jumbotron on the mobile screen?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hello I use the bootstrap jumbotron class and whenever the screen goes below 500 pixels I want to get padding 0 bootstrap automatically padding: 2rem 1rem; but it doesn't work if I want to change it. What is the solution? Thanks in advance for your answers.

```css
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .jumbotron {
      padding:0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="berkay.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:500px)" href="mobile.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="jumbotron row" style="height:100px;">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 mol-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-10">
  <p class="lead">Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can target the element you want to change and use !important in your CSS to override the Bootstrap CSS. However there may be a better way of doing this because using !important everywhere is not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the padding to ***0*** by default with `p-0`, or `px-0` if you want to remove only the horizontal padding (`py-0` for vertical). Then add a padding on larger screen, for exemple `p-md-5` to have an horizontal and vertical padding from ***md*** breakpoint.

You can do it without any custom CSS.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="jumbotron row p-0 p-md-5" style="height:100px;">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 mol-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-10">
        <p class="lead">Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey bro, What should I do if I want to extend the height of the mobile sized jumbotron?

Comment: By default the size is calculated according the content, so you'll have to use custom CSS. But better to create new question to avoid discussion in comment.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:

```css
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .container-fluid .row.jumbotron {
      padding:0px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="berkay.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:500px)" href="mobile.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="jumbotron row" style="height:100px;">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 mol-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-10">
  <p class="lead">Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile-first projects on the web.</p>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey bro, What should I do if I want to extend the height of the mobile sized jumbotron?